# Excel VBA Click Once Application

Tags: excel, clickonce, vba

How Can I add my .xlsb file to a Visual studio tools for office solution? My .xlsb file has VBA code behind.I should be able to publish it as Click Once application ,once I am done with this.

Comment: Hope my understanding is correct which is based on your request and the way your question has been tagged. `ClickOnce` is about deploying your `Application` by publishing to a website. The users can then install the App by clicking on that link. Even if you publish your `.xlsb` file, you will still need Excel in the destination PC for opening it. You cannot create executable files out of your Excel Files.

Comment: And if my understanding on your question is incorrect then I would recommend you to re-phrase it and explain what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes, the destination PC has Excel.So whenever there is a new version of .xlsb..the click Once application has to download the latestversion and backup the older one.I am completely new to these applications

Comment: So my understanding was correct. In such a scenario, I would recommend you to have a look at this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386095.aspx

Comment: I completely understand the concept of publishing the application as clickonce, but I really don't understand ,how can I transform or add my already existing .xlsb file as a Visual studio tools for office solution.

Comment: You have to create a fresh VSTO Solution using vb.net or C#. You cannot deploy your xlsb via Clickonce. Do you know VB.Net or C#?

Answer (score 0):

Let me make sure if I understand your question!!! 
You want to deploy office using click once.

If thats ur question..
    Start a solution using vs, select a type (excel,word...). 
    Get your working xlsb into your solution. 
    Run publish.

You dont have to code anything !!!